# To what extent are sociological views of Christianity allowed here?

Tags: discussion

I have recently come across an interesting article that proposes that Protestant traditions place greater emphasis on faith in religious practice, whereas Catholic traditions place greater emphasis on guilt reduction through active confession and atonement. (Park et al., 1990; Tix & Frazier, 1998) It has also been proposed in the literature that experiencing religious doubts may conflict with the Protestant emphasis on faith and upon grace bestowed upon believers, through a personal relationship with Jesus Christ.

So, can I ask a question about Protestantism/Catholicism and psychology?

Answer (score 3):

If it's what does denomination X think about psychology theory Y, then I think that's fine.

If it's what does psychology theory X imply about denomination Y, then no.